# How I can feed a Custom-View with a View in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I got a CustomVStackView() which I am using it inside my ContentView(), **My Goal** ***is to be able feed CustomVStackView() with an other View from ContentView().***

Here the Code, it has issue with it!

```
    struct ContentView: View {
 
    
    var body: some View {

        CustomVStackView(inPutView: Text("Hello").font(Font.largeTitle) )
        
    }
}


struct CustomVStackView: View {
    

    
    var inPutView: View = EmptyView()
    
    var body: some View {
        

        VStack
        {
            inPutView
 
        }.padding().background(Color.purple)
        
        
    }
}
```

*PS: I know about AnyView() but I am interested to feed my inPutView with a decent normal View() like Text() or Circle() . . .*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to use generics to be able to pass any arbitrary view. In this case, `CustomVStackView` will have a generic type `Content` that conforms to `View`.

If you also use `@ViewBuilder` for the parameter, then the user of `CustomVStackView` would be able to use the same syntax for the inner view that is used for the normal `VStack` (and throughout SwiftUI):

```
struct CustomVStackView<Content: View>: View {
    
    private var inputView: () -> Content

    init(@ViewBuilder inputView: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.inputView = inputView
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack
        {
            inputView()
        }
        .padding().background(Color.purple)
    }
}
```

Usage is:

```
CustomVStackView() {
    Text("Hello").font(Font.largeTitle)
    Text("World")
}
```

Comment: WoW! Thanks, you actually answered my future question with this Answer as well, I wanted go asking how I can feed my CustomView in style of using "{" and "}".